# Why is AUDCLNT_E_ENDPOINT_CREATE_FAILED triggered when I use WASAPI to create an audio endpoint on a Windows computer?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, core-audio, wasapi

I used Core Audio to collect audio on a Windows computer. There was no problem at first, but after calling the initialize interface many times, the `AUDCLNT_E_ENDPOINT_CREATE_FAILED` error message appeared. Does anyone know the reason?

API link is as follows:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclient-initialize

Comment: I don't know why, but I think this problem may be occured due to too many times open/close the audio endpoint, so that os banned this device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer, the computer appeared `AUDCLNT_E_ENDPOINT_CREATE_FAILED`  error msg, because of the Kaspersky anti-virus software baned the audio stream from computer to SDK. Therfore, I configured the white list of software, and SDK run normally.